# Как предотвратить вывод ошибок по throw внутри секций then библиотеки Promise Q?

Tags: angularjs, promise

Я использую библиотеку промисов Q в Ангуляре 1.
У меня есть такой код:

```
$q((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(1);
}).then(function(ret) {
    throw new Error("o_O");
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

В консоли выводится ошибка throw new Error("o_O");
А затем эта ошибка повторно выводится console.log(err);

[image: консоль]

Я хочу чтобы выводилась ошибка только в секции catch.

Как предотвратить вывод ошибок по throw внутри секций then?

Пример кода:
http://plnkr.co/edit/MiH48Qb7tfCEW31mz1ou?p=preview
Для воспроизведения проблемы нужно сначала открыть консоль браузера, потом запустить пример и в консоли будет видно, что сначала выводится по throw, а потом по console.log).

Comment: а никак. При использовании нативных Promise - вывод только один. Попробуй добавить [mcve] - возможно ошибка связана не с библиотекой

Comment: Создал: http://plnkr.co/edit/MiH48Qb7tfCEW31mz1ou?p=preview (там нужно сначала открыть консоль браузера, потом запустить пример и в консоли будет видно, что сначала выводится по throw, а потом по console.log)

Comment: Блин, ну вы бы хоть отладочную версию библиотеки взяли, а не минифицированную...

Comment: Поставил отладочную

Answer (score 1):

Вроде нашел способ обойти эту неприятность. Вместо throw можно воспользоваться $q.reject. Тогда хотя бы свои собственные исключения не будут дублироваться.

```
$q((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(1);
}).then(function(ret) {
    //throw new Error("o_O");
    return $q.reject(new Error("o_O"));
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Этот вариант только для контролируемых ошибок, когда ты сам решаешь, что вот сейчас обещание должно пойти по ветке reject. Если же произойдет неожиданное исключение - все еще будет двойной вывод.

Comment: Я это и указал: "хотя бы свои собственные". Неожиданные придется терпеть))

Comment: Вообще использование нативных Promise вполне себе вариант решения

Comment: Я не знаю как заменить промисс в сервисе $http. Если можно как-то глобально поменять, чтобы ангуляр использовал другую библиотеку, то решение будет идеальным.

Comment: самое топорное решение: переписать сервис `$q`.

Answer (score 0):

В сервисе `$q` используется [своя реализация `Promise`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.x/src/ng/q.js).

В ней процессом обработки занимается функция [`processQueue`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.x/src/ng/q.js#L307)

```
function processQueue(state) {
  var fn, deferred, pending;

  pending = state.pending;
  state.processScheduled = false;
  state.pending = undefined;
  for (var i = 0, ii = pending.length; i < ii; ++i) {
    deferred = pending[i][0];
    fn = pending[i][state.status];
    try {
      if (isFunction(fn)) {
        deferred.resolve(fn(state.value));
      } else if (state.status === 1) {
        deferred.resolve(state.value);
      } else {
        deferred.reject(state.value);
      }
    } catch (e) { // обработка исключений возникших в функциях обратного вызова
      deferred.reject(e); 
      exceptionHandler(e); 
    }
  }
}
```

Как можно заметить, в случае, если в коллбэке происходит исключение, то в блоке `catch` выполняется два действия:

1. планирование выполнения обработчика `reject`
2. вызов `exceptionHandler`

На второй пункт стоит обратить внимание: эта функция в итоге вызывает [`console.error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Console/error) используя сервис `$log`. Именно этот вызов и записывает ошибку в консоль.

Судя по всему для избежания вывода второй раз вместо сервиса `$q` нужно использовать нативные [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ! А я то искал опцию debug, чтобы отключить вывод ошибок внутри then.

Comment: @KhusamovSukhrob, не, как я понял debug отвечает только за то. будут ли выводиться debug сообщения, к ошибкам это никакого отношения вроде как не имеет и поведение нельзя изменить. Но возможно стоит побольше покопаться в исходниках :) либо просто переопределить сервис $log например :)

Comment: Нашел частичное решение. Нужно вместо throw использовать return $q.reject().